# Postgres: Convert TEXT to string or difference between 'abc' vs. 'a' || 'bc'

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I dont understand the difference between String and Text in Postgres. I want to get the estimated count of rows from an table with this function

```sql
 SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate
 FROM   pg_class
 WHERE  oid = to_regclass('schema.tablename');
```

This works, but this will be called from other code which might not be aware the current schema - so i wanted to use the `current_schema()` function.

If i change the code to

```sql
SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  oid = to_regclass(current_schema() || '.tablename');
```

I get following error:

`[42883] ERROR: function to_regclass(text) does not exist Hinweis: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 67`

Even if i try to use `to_regclass('schema' || '.transactions');` i get the same error.

How can i cast the result of "||" to string? There is no "string" data type for CAST(... TO string) and what is the difference between `'schema.tablename'` and `'schema' || '.tablename'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution with the help of the postgresql chat on freenode:

```sql
SELECT reltuples::bigint AS estimate
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  oid = to_regclass((current_schema() || '.table')::cstring);
```

Comment: I found your issue despite using the solution. Edit: Error message complains about `to_regclass(cstring)` instead of `to_regclass(text)`.